# Google App Script to create Google Contacts with blank fields

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-contacts-api

## Background:

I am pushing the contacts list from Google Spreadsheet to Google Contacts, either creating or updating the current Google Contacts. I have got the entire script working except for this tiny problem. As my contact list consists of people from all over the world, I need to account for the different name structure. So there are times when an individual may not have a *"givenName"*.

## Issue:

The method to create a contact in Google Contacts via Google App Script is as `createContact(givenName, familyName, email)`. My current script is bounded to a Google Spreadsheet (*if it matters*).

Is there any way to create a contact without a givenName? or `setGivenName(givenName)` as a blank?

Answer (score 3):

I hope you know that **givenName** stands for the **First Name** of any person and the **familyName** is significantly the **Last Name** of any person. So technically, a person has to have a **First Name**.

But in your case, if you wish to create a contact without any **givenName**, you can achieve this by putting a **whitespace** in the cell corresponding to the contact that does not have a **givenName**. That will work.

Here it is for your reference :

```
var contact = ContactsApp.createContact(' ', 'Gandhi', 'abc@gmail.com');
```

Comment: Is there any way to create without making use of white spaces or any other character? The dataset do not have, and cannot allow for extra white spaces.

Comment: **givenName** is an important/required field, you can not bypass that in any case. Like you cannot get a passport without a name on it, similarly you cannot create a contact without entering something in the **givenName**.

I am sorry that it is not what you are looking for, but what you are looking for is unfortunately not possible.

Comment: As much as it is useful in a normal use case, the order of the name is important and it is even more important that certain fields are stored separated. That's why we're using the Prefix and Suffix as well _(which is why givenName is sometimes left empty)_. But thanks for your help!